# Looking To Output To An Excel File

Tags: command-line

I am looking to output the contents of a folder (and all subfolders) with the last modified date and time.

The following would be the format if running from the D Drive.

D:\ExcelFile1.xls        01-01-2015

D:\ExcelFile2.xls        01-01-2015

D:\ExcelFile3.xls        01-01-2015

D:\ExcelFile4.xls        01-01-2015

D:\ExcelFile5.xls        01-01-2015

D:\ExcelFile6.xls        01-01-2015

D:\MyWordDocuments\WordDoc11.xls        01-02-2015

D:\MyWordDocuments\WordDoc12.xls        03-01-2015

D:\MyWordDocuments\WordDoc13.xls        04-01-2015

D:\MyWordDocuments\WordDoc14.xls        05-01-2015

D:\MyWordDocuments\WordDoc15.xls        06-01-2015

D:\PowerpointFolder                     15-04-2016

Comment: Welcome to stackechange. It's proper etiquette (and just plain helpful) to show what you've tried and where you are confused. As of right now, you're "question" is just you telling us what you want us to do for you.

Comment: You are probably looking for recursive lookup and writing to file. You can import a .txt document to excel if it has some kind of delimiter like per line or ; or ,

Comment: Hi, Apologies for not giving more information about what I have tried. I have found the command line of dir /b /s > index.txt gives me 90% of what I am looking for. All I need is what to add so that the last modified date and time is added to the output.